# How to suppress text output after plotting in Jupyer notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When you want to update plotting parameters in python using `mpl.rcParams.update(params)`, it prints an array to the number of plots you have, say if you use hist for 12 parameters you get an array of 12 lines as

```
array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1d27fc50>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1d6292e8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1d63b6d8>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1e922c50>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1e955208>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1e97c780>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1e9a3cf8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1e9d52e8>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1e9d5320>],
       [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1ea25da0>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1ea55358>,
        <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x1a1ea7d8d0>]],
      dtype=object)
```

How can I avoid/suppress this being printed in jupyter notebook.

Sample Code:

```
params = {'axes.titlesize':'60', 'xtick.labelsize':'24', 'ytick.labelsize':'24'} 
mpl.rcParams.update(params);
data.hist(figsize=(50, 30), bins=10)
```

Comment: The text that is displayed is actually generated by your `data.hist()` command, and has nothing to do with rcParams.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A better option would be to call `plt.show()` at the end of the cell. This way your plots will be shown even in case you convert the notebook to a standalone python script

Answer (score 3):

Try putting a semicolon at the end of the python command which produces this output. If that did not work, put a `%%capture` at the beginning of the cell.

Comment: In python I have not heard of semicolon to work :) capture actually suppresses the whole plot in the block, and no plotting.

Comment: well, it's not python, its jupyter notebook. Did you try semicolon?

Comment: Semicolon should work. Did you place it with your call to `hist`?

Answer (score 0):

I find this is also useful:
`data.hist(figsize=(50, 30), bins=10)[2]`
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to prevent spurious text above your graph is to end your code block with

```
None
```

Explanation: Jupyter captures the result from the last line of your code cell and typesets it "output." This is true even when your intended output is only your graph. Although Matplotlib functions are typically used for their "side effect" of modifying your graph, many of them also return arrays of handles, which Jupyter duly pastes into your "output" cell. Adding a single line of code that explicitly has no result (`None`) causes Jupyter to instead paste that "no result" into the "output" cell.